# Issue with CURL with IIS on getting post data

Tags: iis, curl, zend-framework2

I have a site that connects using cURL (latest version) to Our API (IIS) server. My solution is working fine for wamp and XAMPP but getting issue in IIS

I am not able to get post data on API server.

//Code Snippets

$client = new HttpClient();

```
    $client->setAdapter('Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\Curl');

    $url = (isset($apiUrl) && $apiUrl != NULL ) ? $apiUrl : CustomConstantsFunction::apiCommunityUrl();
    $client->setUri($url);

    $headers = $client->getRequest()->getHeaders();
    $headers->addHeaderLine('Authorization', \Application\Functions\CustomConstantsFunction::encryptDecrypt('encrypt',$host.'-ZendCommunityProduct-'.$todayTimestamp));

    $client->setMethod('POST');

    $client->setParameterPOST($postData);

    $client->setHeaders($headers);
    $client->setOptions(array(
        'maxredirects' => 1,
        'timeout'      => 300,
        'curloptions' => array(
            CURLOPT_HEADER => 1,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
            CURLOPT_UNRESTRICTED_AUTH => TRUE,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE,
        )
    ));
    $response = $client->send();
    $response = $response->getBody();
    $data = json_decode($response);        
    return $data;
```

I have also tried cURL'ing different sites and they return content fine but they are not helpful to me.

Has anyone else experienced this error and know a work around?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below api url

```
    $url = (isset($apiUrl) && $apiUrl != NULL ) ? $apiUrl."/" : CustomConstantsFunction::apiCommunityUrl();
```

And also changed $client setOptions parameters.

```
    $client->setOptions(array(
        'maxredirects' => 2,
        'timeout'      => 300
    ));
```

its working for me. :)